# How to sort buckets aggregation from query with wildcard?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm can't figure out how sorting the buckets results. I'm using ES 6.3 and [following suggested docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html). I'm trying to sort the results putting "bucket_sort" aggregation, but getting error. The follow query works but returns the buckets in same order no matter I put "sort" clause with 'asc' or 'desc' after "query" body:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool":{
        "filter":{
            "wildcard": {
                    "datas.295.keyword": {
                        "value":"*w*"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
},
"sort":[
    {
    "datas.295.keyword": {
        "order" : "desc"
    }
    }
],
"aggs": {
    "AGGREGATE_UNIQUE_VALUES_FROM_REPEATED": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "datas.295.keyword"
        }
    }
}}
```

returning records matchs with operating system windows XP, Windows Vista etc. But How to sort it in ascending order? I'm try this:

```
{

"query": {
    "bool":{
        "filter":{
            "wildcard": {
                    "datas.295.keyword": {
                        "value":"*w*"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "AGGREGATE_UNIQUE_VALUES_FROM_REPEATED": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "datas.295.keyword"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "bucket_sort":{
                "sort": [
                    {
                        "datas.295.keyword": {"order": "asc"}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

This query raising 'Expected [START_OBJECT] under [sort], but got a [START_ARRAY] in [bucket_sort]' error
Thank for read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hits and aggs are separate parts of the API. What you need is the terms' [bucket order](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "wildcard": {
          "datas.295.keyword": {
            "value": "*w*"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "datas.295.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "AGGREGATE_UNIQUE_VALUES_FROM_REPEATED": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "datas.295.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```